# HTC desire BluetoothSocket connect freezes

Tags: android, bluetooth

I working on project, involving BT connection. I have performed tests with phones like Nexus S, Nexus Galaxy and everything worked good.
The issue is with HTC desire. First of all, I have to connect to PC via port, so I use reflection

```
Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket",
            new Class[] { int.class });
BluetoothSocket socket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, port);
socket.connect();
```

socket.connect() freezes the thread forever, just like socket.close();
Also from Android logs I can see strange messages:

> USERIAL_Ioctl: BT_Sleep, USERIAL_IO_BT_WAKE_DEASSERT

Reboot didn't help. But the strange thing, that issue is reproducable time to time.

Thanks for any comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a workaround.
Socket.connect() should be called from another thread.

If it would block executing thread, we can stop it, using
Socket.close();